# paste image without background PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to paste many small grayscale images into a bigger one. All images are jpegs. The small images had been previously rotated, so they have black background. What I wanted to do is to paste them without a background color, in other words, I need the background color to be transparent.

Thank you for your suggestions,

Comment: Given your rotated images now with a black background, does the color black appear anywhere inside the actual images ? If it does, then it might be possible by detecting the stronger edges in the image that (hopefully) defines the implicit rectangle present in the rotated image and then ignore what is outside of the rectangle. If it does not, then it is much easier to solve the problem. Can you refine your problem taking this into consideration ?

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge, jpg does not support transparency, you probably want your output to be a png, and you will need to set the alpha channel to be nothing

http://www.talkgraphics.com/showthread.php?22385-How-do-I-make-jpeg-image-background-transparent